# How to save quick property changes from UI (main) thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, magicalrecord

I am using MagicalRecord and I am trying to figure out the easiest way to save the changes that a user is making while interacting with the UI.

From the MagicalRecord docs I know I can use a background thread:

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {

    // Do your work to be saved here, against the `localContext` instance
    // Everything you do in this block will occur on a background thread

} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    // done
}];
```

That works and is not too bad, but comes with some extra overhead and you have to make sure all entities you deal with inside the block are part of the localContext.

But lets say I have 3 properties that are set from the UI and the user clicks save:

```
- (void) onSaveTapped {
   entity.property1 = @"foo";
   entity.property2 = @"bar";
   entity.property3 = @"tar";
}
```

At this point is it ok just to grab the default context magical record has (main thread) and save?

```
NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
// Save the changes to the defaultContext
// Entity was part of that same context as it was used in the UI thread, just save that context
[defaultContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL contextDidSave, NSError *error) {
    // done
}];
```

From what I understand MagicalRecords defaultContext has a parent that is on the background thread, and that parent will save to the persistent store.  Meaning this should not block the UI thread when saving to the store.

Question in summary:
Is the saveWithBlock method for things like importing large amounts of data into core data when those entities are not part of the main threads contexts?  And when saving entities that were part of the UI can you just call MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion?